# Multiple alignments of equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

I have three equations of different lengths, each having alignments within them (at the '=' and'+') sign. However, I also want to align the three equations at the first '=' of each equation (marked in yellow in the picture below) and also maintain the space between them ,which is produced by the three align environments.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_1}  &=  \sum_{i: x_i =0} y_i .... \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} + \sum_{i: y_i > 0} 2y_i + ab
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_2} &=  \sum_{i: x_i =0} y_i + 2y_{i}^{2} \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} + \sum_{i: y_i > 0} 2y_i + ab + 2x
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_3} &=  \sum_{i: x_i =0} y_i + (y+1)^2 - (y-1)^2 \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} + \sum_{i: y_i > 0} 2y_i + ab
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I have tried it by using the alignat command but I did not manage to obtain the result I want . The result at the moment looks like
[image]

Comment: you should never have adjacent math displays just use a single `align`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the simplest way to achieve what you want is really to use a single `align*` environment. Then you can manually add some extra spacing between the three expressions in the optional argument of `\\`, when switching lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_1}  &=  \sum_{i: x_i =0} y_i .... \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} + \sum_{i: y_i > 0} 2y_i + ab \\[4mm]
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_2} &=  \sum_{i: x_i =0} y_i + 2y_{i}^{2} \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} + \sum_{i: y_i > 0} 2y_i + ab + 2x \\[4mm]
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_3} &=  \sum_{i: x_i =0} y_i + (y+1)^2 - (y-1)^2 \\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} + \sum_{i: y_i > 0} 2y_i + ab
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

In addition to employing a single `align*` environment, I would also like to recommend that you encase all six `\sum` terms in `\smashoperator` "wrappers" to achieve a more compact appearance of the equations. (Basically, the `\smashoperator` directives let the summation subscript terms protrude to the left and right without this messing up the spacing to the left and right of the `\sum` symbols.) I would also replace all instances of `&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}` with either `&\quad` or `&\qquad`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} % 'mathtools' loads 'amsmath' automatically

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_1}  
  &=       \smashoperator{\sum_{i: x_i =0}} y_i \dots \\
  &\qquad+ \smashoperator{\sum_{i: y_i > 0}} 2y_i + ab \\[\jot]
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_2} 
  &=       \smashoperator{\sum_{i: x_i =0}} y_i + 2y_{i}^{2} \\
  &\qquad+ \smashoperator{\sum_{i: y_i > 0}} 2y_i + ab + 2x \\[\jot]
\frac{\partial F(\phi)}{\partial \beta_3} 
  &=       \smashoperator{\sum_{i: x_i =0}} y_i + (y+1)^2 - (y-1)^2 \\
  &\qquad+ \smashoperator{\sum_{i: y_i > 0}} 2y_i + ab
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on @Mico's nice answer (+1) but with use of `\pdv` of `derivative` package and
`multlined` environment, `\smashoperator` and `\mathrlap` of `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % it load amsmath too
\usepackage{derivative}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
\pdv{F(\phi)}{\beta_1}  
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \smashoperator{\sum_{i:x_i=0}}  \mathrlap{y_i \dots} \\
            + \smashoperator{\sum_{i:y_i>0}}    2y_i + ab
        \end{multlined}     \\[\jot]
%
\pdv{F(\phi)}{\beta_2}
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \smashoperator{\sum_{i:x_i=0}}  \mathrlap{y_i + 2y_{i}^{2}} \\
            + \smashoperator{\sum_{i:y_i>0}}    2y_i + ab + 2x
        \end{multlined}     \\[\jot]
%
\pdv{F(\phi)}{\beta_3}
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \smashoperator{\sum_{i:x_i=0}}  \mathrlap{y_i + (y+1)^2 - (y-1)^2} \\
            + \smashoperator{\sum_{i:y_i>0}}    2y_i + ab
        \end{multlined}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice touch with `\pdv`, but are you sure about the use of `\mathrlap`? Use your code in a two-column setup and change `\mathrlap{y_i + (y+1)^2 - (y-1)^2}` to `\mathrlap{y_i + (y+1)^2 - (y-1)^2-(y-2)^2}` to see what I mean.

Comment: @Mico, without of `\mathrlap{...}` the beginning of the second rows in `multlined`s are not horizontally  aligned (in the last `multlined` is pushed to right). Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: In my opinion, the main issue with `\mathrlap` is that the  contents of its argument may well protrude outside the text block, especially if a two-column layout is in use.

Comment: @Mico, you are right, but, did you test my solution without `\mathrlap`? Using it, it is enabled that the first line of `multlined` math can protrude to the right without to has influence on the position of the next (second) line.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IEEEtrantools package. Effortless alignment of multiple and complex equations. Separate multiple eqns with \\ and use  \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{} and \end{IEEEeqnarray}. Three alignment choices in the begin bracket.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{memoir}  
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} %for aligning eqns with multiple lines  

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  
\overline{C_2B} &=& r = \dfrac{\sqrt {9\Phi^{2}+1} }{2}\,tis.\nonumber \\\  

\overline{BX} &=& \mbox{midface of pentagon to a vertex of pentagon} = \dfrac{\Phi}{\sqrt {\Phi^{2}+1} }\,tis. \nonumber \\\

h^{2} &=& \overline {C_{2} B}^{2}-\overline {BX} 
^{2}=\dfrac{9\Phi^{2}+1}{4}-\dfrac{\Phi^{2}}{\Phi^{2}+1}\nonumber \\\ 

&=& \dfrac{(\Phi^{2}+1)(9\Phi^{2}+1)-4\Phi^{2}}{4(\Phi 
^{2}+1)}\nonumber \\\

&=&\dfrac{9\Phi^{4}+6\Phi^{2}+1}{4(\Phi 
^{2}+1)}=\dfrac{(3\Phi^{2}+1)^{2}}{4(\Phi^{2}+1)}\nonumber \\\ 

h &=& \dfrac{3\Phi^{2}+1}{2\sqrt {\Phi^{2}+1} }\,tis=2.327438437\,tis.
  
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
```

Looks like this:
[image]

The same equations with change in the first parameter from {rCl} to {cCl}centers the left side of each equation

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{cCl}
[image]

The same equations with change in the first parameter from {lCl} to {lCl} moves the left side of each equation all the way to the left

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{lCl}
[image]

This system is very flexible and allows the alignment of eqns pretty much where you want them.

Comment: Please add MWE with OP equations, which will generate result as OP like to get.  Show this result too.